# Why slide up doesn't work if I use ul tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to pull up/slide up my Html "p" tag when my page has been loaded.

This jQuery code works fine and does that:

```
$(function () {
    $('.graybgc').slideUp(0);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p class="graybgc">
    <span>A: </span>abcd.....
</p>
```

But when I put some tags like ul, it doesn't works and doesn't pull up HTML p tag.

```
 <p class="graybgc">
       <span>A: </span>
          <ul >
            <li>123</li>
             <li>123</li>
          </ul>
</p>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a <ul> or an <ol> inside a p tag. It isn't proper HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put a `ul` tag inside of a `p` tag. Please check [HTML specification](https://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

Here is a working example using `div` tag (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/sa09gu46/) :

```js
$('.graybgc').on('click', function() {
    $(this).slideUp(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graybgc" >
    <span>A: </span>
    <ul>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use <DIV> instead of <p>

```
<div class="graybgc">
       <span>A: </span>
          <ul >
            <li>123</li>
             <li>123</li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.graybgc').on('click', function() {
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graybgc" style="background:red" >
    <span>A: </span>
    <ul>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please replace 0 with slow to see the effect the first value you enter in the slideup is the time of animation. hope it will help you.